# Box2d SetLinearVelocity weird issue

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am trying to get a b2body object follow the touch location in a constant speed and I have a problem in the "y" axis in which the body go to the location on the "other half of the screen" 
like a mirror image...the "x" axis is fine though.
(I am using cocos2d 1.0.0)

Here is all the code:

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"

#define PTM_RATIO 32.0

@interface HelloWorldLayer : CCLayer {
    b2World *_world;
    b2Body *_body;
    CCSprite *_ball;
}

+ (id) scene;

@end
```

HelloWorldLayer.m

```
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "CGPointExtension.h"

static CGPoint location;

@implementation HelloWorldLayer

+ (id)scene {

    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
    return scene;

}

- (id)init {

    if ((self=[super init])) {
        CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

        // Create sprite and add it to the layer
        _ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 52, 52)];
        _ball.position = ccp(100, 300);
        [self addChild:_ball];

        // Create a world
        b2Vec2 gravity = b2Vec2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        _world = new b2World(gravity);

        // Create edges around the entire screen
        b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
        groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);

        b2Body *groundBody = _world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
        b2EdgeShape groundEdge;
        b2FixtureDef boxShapeDef;
        boxShapeDef.shape = &groundEdge;

        //wall definitions
        groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
        groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

        groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(0,0), b2Vec2(0,winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
        groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

        groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(0, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO),
                       b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO));
        groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

        groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO),
                       b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, 0));
        groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

        // Create ball body and shape
        b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
        ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        ballBodyDef.position.Set(100/PTM_RATIO, 300/PTM_RATIO);
        ballBodyDef.userData = _ball;
        _body = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

        b2CircleShape circle;
        circle.m_radius = 26.0/PTM_RATIO;

        b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
        ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
        ballShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
        ballShapeDef.friction = 0.2f;
        ballShapeDef.restitution = 0.8f;
        _body->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);

        [self schedule:@selector(tick:)];
        [self setTouchEnabled:YES];
        [self setAccelerometerEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tick:(ccTime) dt {

    int32 velocityIterations = 8;
    int32 positionIterations = 1;
    _world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

    for(b2Body *b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *ballData = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
            ballData.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                    b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
            ballData.rotation = 1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
        }
    }

}

-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));


}
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    [self schedule:@selector(asd:)];


}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

   // [self unschedule:@selector(asd:)];
   // _body->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0,0));
   // _body->SetAngularVelocity(0);
    //_body->SetActive(false);
}

-(void)asd:(ccTime) dt {

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(location));

    //float ca = location.y;

        b2Vec2 convertedLocation = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO - _body->GetPosition().x, location.y/PTM_RATIO - _body->GetPosition().y);

        //b2Vec2 toTouchPoint = convertedLocation - _body->GetPosition();

        convertedLocation.Normalize();
        b2Vec2 impulse = 5 * convertedLocation;

        _body->SetLinearVelocity(impulse);

     //  _body->ApplyLinearImpulse(_body->GetMass() * impulse, _body->GetWorldCenter());




}


- (void)dealloc {
    delete _world;
    _body = NULL;
    _world = NULL;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: debug your code. Probably the y value of touch location is negative

Answer (score 1):

when you get the location from a touch using locationInView, the origin is at the top left corner. where as in cocos2D origin lies at the bottom left corner. you can flip the y value. or alternatively you can use the  ConvertToGL function of the CCDirector. I prefer the later mainly because it handles all the portrait and landscape modes.

```
CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:touch.view]
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:loc];
```